# ERROR " ERROR Converting datatype Varchar to Float" Creating Extract of SQL Server Data Source

Tags: sql-server, cognos-10

I am creating Report By using Cognos Report Studio,

I have SQL Server As a Data Source,
When i tried to convert varchar field to float in framework manager then got error message

[image]

but when i used Notes DB as a Data Source then i am getting data without any error
( i have one data 35-40 and getting result 35) 
but while using SQL Server getting error.
how to convert varchar field to float inside framework manager if we have SQL server as a Source

Comment: You have some data in at least one column that is being converted to a real and the data is invalid for that. I would ask why you are storing numbers as strings in the first place.

Comment: Read your last comment and ask yourself what that is even attempting to say. It makes no sense at all.

Comment: basically,before we had Notes DB as a source but now repoint Framework manager to SQL Server then we are getting this error inside framework manager, i tried buy cast operator but got error @Sean